# Как передать логин/пароль при подключении к серверу с винды через Самба?

Tags: samba

Как правило для подключения к серверу через "Самба" достаточно в строку поиска в меню "Пуск" вбить `\\\ip-address`, при этом подключение происходит от лица текущего пользователя.

Как быть, если я хочу подключиться от лица другого пользователя?

Как передать логин/пароль?

Comment: \\username:password@ip-address, по-моему

Comment: Почему он заходит от лица текущего пользователя? Он должен запрашивать логин и пароль. Посмотрите в "Диспетчере учетных данных", не заполнена ли там учетка.